# pass value to function in form of <select>

Tags: javascript

All I want to pass a `<select> </select>` value to a JavaScript function.
Here is my code:

```
function test() {
   var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="test()">
  <select  name="gender" id="gender">
     <option selected="" value="Default">select</option>
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>  
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `form.serialize()` to get form data

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var element = document.getElementById("gender");
var gender = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a submit button in there so I assume you want to harness the onChange event of the select. Here is how you would do that:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
  <select  name="gender" id="gender" onChange="test()">
     <option selected="" value="Default">select</option>
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
</form>

function test()
{
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
  console.log('Gender:', gender);
}
```

And a jsbin link to see it in action:

https://jsbin.com/zasexewuta/2/edit?html,js,console,output